# MySQL: retrieving the newest inserted data

Tags: mysql

After inserting new data into a table, I need to select some of the new data straight after, so I can use it for inserting into another table.

The only way I can think of doing this is using the 'datetime' field I have in my row, but how would I retrieve the latest date/time inserted.

1. `INSERT` statement with `NOW()` value for `datetime`
2. `society_select = SELECT socID, creator, datetime FROM societies.society WHERE datetime='[..datetime is the newest...]';`

Hope that makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Can you provide more info about what you're trying to achieve? maybe we can propose an easier way ...

Comment: The way you provided worked, thank you. I just needed it for when a user creates a new society, and it is saved, the user is added to the 'members' table. this was to take place all in the click of the save button, so needed to retrieve the new society created by the user right away, in order for the user to be added as a member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.

Why not make use of a trigger for this?

When a trigger creates a record you can get the id's of the records inserted. You can then do a select and insert new values into the relevant table.

MYSQL has loads of resources on using triggers.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Or you can get the number of rows affected then use this to get the required result set in a select statement.

Get the last inserted ID?

If you are inserting one row into the database at a time then you would be able to get the last inserted id from MYSQL. This will be the Primary Key value of the record you last inserted into the database.

You would basically do something like this in mysql:

```
SET @inserted_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Or in PHP you can use the function:

```
mysql_insert_id(&mysql);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: Thank you, still exploring a lot of functions for MySQL so thank you again, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the results by their datetime in descending order, and select the first of them.

`society_select = SELECT socID, creator, datetime FROM societies.society ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this with an auto increment filed. after inserting data you can retrieve the list inserted id from the table. and use that id to get the latest record.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger as suggested is an option. If you don't want to use that for some kind of reason you can:

- Add an integer primary key with auto_increment as ID and sort it DESC (e.g. INT(11))
- Sort descending on a timestamp column (ofcourse with an index on it)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) after inserting the data. This is for sure the cleaner way.

Another option is to use a method like [mysql_insert_id](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php). Assumed that you use PHP. There are of course equivalent methods in other languages as well.

**Sorting is not an option(if not wrapped smart in transaction)** - If you have multiple writes and reads on the table this might end up pretty ugly.